# How to replace custom HTML tag with another tag, using the same content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to create your own text contents (text between the HTML tags) of my custom HTML tags?

I used this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("eg").replaceWith("<h2>Put the text content of eg here</h2>");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <eg>My text</eg>
</body>
</html>
```

Between the `<h2>` tags (don’t think I should only use `<h2>` tags without JS) in my JavaScript code, any text can be placed that I like to have.

Example: `<eg>I can type any text here but it’ll be still in h2 tag settings</eg>`.

What should I write between `<eg></eg>` in JS to have any `<h2>` text content that will be written in my HTML code?

Comment: `$('eg').text('my text');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the `<eg>Test</eg>` with `<h2>Test</h2>` then you can just do this: `$("eg").replaceWith("<h2>" + $("eg").html() + "</h2>");`.

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/urd69pJSXQngGIsYYSjq

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you just want to append an element to the DOM, so you can just use the html method as follows:

```
  $("eg").html("<h2>Any text can be placed here</h2>");
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/) if you need more info.

Note: You closed but didn't open your body tag.

Replace:

```
</body>
```

With something like:

```
<body> <eg> Your custom content is between body tags now </eg> </body>
```

And you also have two HTML tags, remove the second

```
<html>
```

Answer (score -1):

No. It wouldn't be HTML anymore.
However, if you wrote xHTML (which is a form of XML), then you could extend the DOM with your own elements. But that would be [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), not HTML.

And if you tried adding custom elements to a page, browsers wouldn't know what to do with them. Even if some browsers might display them, it's a very bad idea. Use a class name instead.

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? This answer, while not a great answer due to the little amount of details, is still valid today. I won't teach someone to shoot themselves in the foot even if there's a way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Creating and using custom tags is a bad idea. It should be avoided.

You are probably looking for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#my_h2").html("<h2>Any text can be placed here</h2>");
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <h2 id="my_h2"></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

For more, read-up on CSS selectors. (They are the same as jQuery selectors.)

**Hope this helps.**